# Extract email id of specific domain extensions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I need to extract email id from each row of specific domain extensions like .com .net .org everything else should be ignored. Below is the sample data of two rows.

```
    .@.3,.@.1601466914865855,.@.,.@.null,.@.,abc@xyz.com,abc@xyz.net,abc@xyz.org,null.val@.@.,.@@,abc@xyz.jpb,abc@xyz.xls,abc@xyz.321
.@.3,.@.1601466914865855,.@.,.@.null,.@.,123@hjk.com,123@hjk.net,123@hjk.org,null.val@.@.,.@@,abc@xyz.jpb,abc@xyz.xls,abc@xyz.321
```

Whatever the first valid extension email matches is enough even though there are multiple id's only one email id is enough per row. Below is the sample desired result.

[image: Sample data image]

I believe this can be done with custom formula with regex but I can't wrap my head around it. I am using Desktop MS Excel latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your email addresses are relatively simple, you can use this regex:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

In VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Function extrEmail(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b"
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = True
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        extrEmail = MC(0)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Matching an email address can become very complicated, and a regex that follows all the rules is extraordinarily complex and long.  But this one is relatively simple, and might work for your needs.

**Explanation of Regex**

***Emailaddress1***

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at a word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- [Match a single character present in the list below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z0-9._%+-]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [A character in the range between “A” and “Z”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
  - [A character in the range between “0” and “9”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `0-9`
  - [A single character from the list “._%+”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `._%+`
  - [The literal character “-”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
- [Match the character “@” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `@`
- [Match a single character present in the list below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z0-9.-]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [A character in the range between “A” and “Z”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
  - [A character in the range between “0” and “9”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `0-9`
  - [The literal character “.”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `.`
  - [The literal character “-”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
- [Match the character “.” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.`
- [Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z]{2,}`

  - [Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2,}`
- [Assert position at a word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

[image]

**EDIT:** To match only specific domains, merely replace the part of the regex that matches domains with a group of pipe-separated domain names.

eg

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:com|net|org)\b
```

Comment: Your solution works for me partly. Is there any possibility capture specific domain extension emails as I have stated in my question. .com .net .org and ignore everything else. As above example sample data there are email ids with other extension which should be captured. like abc@xyz.jpb,abc@xyz.xls,abc@xyz.321

Comment: @ACE You merely replace the part of the regex that is matching the domain name portion with a list of what you want to match.  See my edit for an example. You should be able to change that to your specifications.